# $X_{1},X_{2},X_{3}\overset{i.i.d.}{\sim}N(0,1)$, find m.g.f. of $Y=X_{1}X_{2}+X_{1}X_{3}+X_{2}X_{3}$

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I tried this

$X_{1}X_{2}+X_{1}X_{3}+X_{2}X_{3}=X_{1}(X_{2}+X_{3})+\frac{1}{4}(X_{2}+X_{3})^{2}-\frac{1}{4}(X_{2}-X_{3})^{2}$

$U=X_{2}+X_{3}\sim N(0,2)$

$\psi_{X_{1}(X_{2}+X_{3})}(t)=\psi_{X_{1}U}(t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}\cdot 2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{x_{1}ut}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x_{1}^{2}+\frac{u^{2}}{2})}\, dx_{1}\, du$

$=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}\cdot 2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{1}{4}(2(x_{1}-ut)^{2}-2u^{2}t^{2}+u^{2})}\, dx_{1}\, du$

$V=(x_{1}-ut)\qquad dv=dx_{1}\\
        =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}\cdot 2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{1}{4}(1-2t^{2})u^{2}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{1}{2}v^{2}}\, dv\, du\\$

$=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}\cdot 2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{1}{4}(1-2t^{2})u^{2}}\, du$

$ w=\sqrt{\frac{1-2t^{2}}{2}}u,\qquad \sqrt{\frac{2}{1-2t^{2}}}\, dw=du\\
    \psi_{XU}(t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-2t^{2}}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}w^{2}}\, dw=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-2t^{2}}}$

$Z=X_{2}-X_{3}\sim N(0,2)$

$\psi_{\frac{1}{4}(X_{1}+X_{2})^{2}}(t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{\frac{1}{4}z^{2}t}e^{-\frac{1}{4}z^{2}}\, dz$

$=\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{1}{4}(z^{2}-z^{2}t)}\, dz=\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{1}{4}(1-t)z^{2}}\, dz\\$

$v=\sqrt{1-t}z,\quad \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t}}\, dv=dz\\
        \psi_{\frac{1}{4}(X_{1}+X_{2})^{2}}(t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{4}z^{2}}\,dz=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t}}$

$\psi_{\frac{1}{4}(X_{1}+X_{2})^{2}-\frac{1}{4}(X_{2}-X_{3})^{2}}(t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t}}\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-(-t)}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{(1-t)(1+t)}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^{2}}}$

$\psi_{X_{1}(X_{2}+X_{3})+\frac{1}{4}(X_{2}+X_{3})^{2}-\frac{1}{4}(X_{2}-X_{3})^{2}}(t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-2t^{2}}}\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^{2}}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-2t^{2}}\sqrt{1-t^{2}}}$

But I have learned that this is incorrect. What mistakes did I make?

Comment: Do not cross-post across sites please.

Comment: Ok, sorry. I was unsure where the question belonged.

Comment: Also answered at https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/478495/119261.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The the three terms in the first line are not independent. How can you just multiply the MGF's to get the MGF of their sum? MGF of $X+Y$ is the product of the MGF's of $X$ and $Y$ if $X$ and $Y$ are independent, not in general.